# How can I use pyautogui with a keyboard key?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I want to run the while loop I wrote in Pyautogui with any keyboard key, but I don't know how to do it.

I want to make an auto clicker application. In this application, I want the automatic click to be turned on when the key we specify is pressed, and I want it to be turned off when another key we select is pressed.